# How do I update a state each second for next n seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state variable `resendTime` and `magicLinkState`.

I would like to `setResendTime` to `resendTime - 1` for next 10 seconds when magicLinkState becomes sent.

I have tried the following code but this does not update resendTime every second.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (magicLinkState === "sent" && resendTime > 0) {
    const timer = setInterval(() => setResendTime(resendTime - 1), 1000);
    console.log(resendTime);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []);
```

This code only updates the state for the first second. I have also tried passing dependency array but didn't worked.
How do I make it update the state so I achieve what is intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is correct in your code but needs some adjustments.

1. it's required to add the `magicLinkState` to the effect's dependencies otherwise it won't trigger when this gets the `sent` value but only if it's initially set with this value.
2. you should use the arrow syntax: `setResendTime((prevResendTime) => prevResendTime - 1)` in order to grab the correct state value each time
3. there is no need for a cleanup function in this effect since you want to clear the interval only after it's triggered and made 10 decreases to `resendTime`.
4. you should add some local `count` variable in order for the decrease to happen 10 times only and not forever

After these changes your code should look like below:

```
 const decreaseResentTime = (prevResendTime) => prevResendTime - 1;

 useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    if (magicLinkState === "sent" && resendTime > 0) {
      let count = 0;
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (count < 10) {
          count++;
          setResendTime(decreaseResentTime );
        } else {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [magicLinkState]);
```

You can find an example that demonstrates this solution in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shirley-n9zh6s?file=/src/App.js).

There are more improvements to be made here but they are based on your needs. For example if the `magicLinkState` changes to 'sent' and then to something else and then back to 'sent' within the 10 seconds, 2 intervals will run and decrease at a double rate.

Comment: This `useEffect` doesn't clean up after itself. It could `setResendTime` on an unmounted component or if `magicLinkState` changes more than once, you could have multiple `setInterval`s running at the same time.

Comment: Indeed, I have mentioned this on the end of my answer. However you can't just cleanup the interval there but you need some logic based on your needs. That's why I didn't include it here.

Answer (score 0):

You've just an issue of a stale closure over the initial `resendTime` state value. This is easily fixed by using a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to correctly access the previous state value instead of whatever is closed over in the surround callback scope.

```
const timerRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  if (magicLinkState === "sent" && resendTime > 0) {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setResendTime(resendTime => resendTime - 1); // <-- functional update
    }, 1000);
    timerRef.current = timer;
    
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, []);
```

Note also that because of the closure that if you want to log the `resendTime` state *as* it updates you'll need to use a another `useEffect` hook with a proper dependency. This is also where you'd move the logic to check if the interval is completed. Use a React ref to store a reference to the timer id.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (resendTime <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }
  console.log(resendTime);
}, [resendTime]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can I use timestamps instead of intervals? this function checks every second for 10 seconds when called once

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (magicLinkState === "sent" && resendTime > 0) {
        let startTimeforTenSeconds = Date.now();
        let startTimeforEachSecond = Date.now();

        const nonBlockingCommand = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            while (true) {
                const currentTime = Date.now();

                if (currentTime - startTimeforEachSecond >= 1000) {
                    startTimeforEachSecond = Date.now();
                    console.log("1 seconds have passed. set resend time here");
                    // code for resending time here
                    setResendTime(resendTime - 1);
                    console.log(resendTime );
                }

                if (currentTime - startTimeforTenSeconds >= 10000) {
                    console.log("10 seconds have passed. stop checking.");
                    resolve("10 seconds have passed.");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        nonBlockingCommand.then(() => console.log('function is done'));
    }
}, []);
```

EDIT: Result screenshot:
[image: EDIT: Result screenshot:]

Comment: Have you tested this code? This code has the same issue as OP's where `resendTime` doesn't change. I also think it will block the main JS thread.

Comment: yeah tested it, I'll add a screenshot for you. you can add the initial value of resendTime if you are concerned with resendTime value testing:
```function setResendTime(val) {
    resendTime = val;
}

let resendTime = 10;```